# How to Mock Sequelize Models with Relations in Jest for NestJS?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, backend

I'm trying to write tests for modules in NestJS. One of the models I have has a relationship with another model. When I mock it, I encounter the following error:

```
const mockInvoiceModel = {}

beforeEach(async () => {
  const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    providers: [InvoiceService, { provide: getModelToken(InvoiceModel), useValue: mockInvoiceModel }],
  }).compile();
```

Error:

```
Cannot find module 'src/subscription/models/subscription.model' from 'invoice/models/invoice.model.ts
```

and this is the relations of Invoice model:

```
@ForeignKey(() => SubscriptionModel)
@Column({type: DataType.UUID })
subscriptionId: UUID;

@BelongsTo(() => SubscriptionModel)
subscription: SubscriptionModel;

@HasMany(() => TransactionModel)
payments: TransactionModel[];
```

The invoice model has a relationship with subscription. How can I mock this model?

I expected that by providing a mock value for the InvoiceModel using getModelToken(InvoiceModel) in the testing module

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by changing the file imports from `src/subscription/models/subscription.model` to `../subscription/models/subscription.model`.